# Looking for references on the complexity of computation of a basis transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, computational-complexity, numerical-linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm looking for some references on the complexity for the following kind of problem:

Given two Basis $(a_1, ... ,a_n)$ and $(b_1, ..., b_n)$ of the $K(x)$-vector space $V$ I want to compute the transformation matrix $M \in K(x)^{n \times n}$ which satifies the equation
$$ (b_1, ..., b_n) \cdot M = (a_1, ... ,a_n).$$

Either I simply don't know the name of this kind of problem or there is another rather trivial reason that I can't find any references.
There has been much effort in scientific research solving linear equations of the form
$$ Ax = b  $$
for given $A$ and $b$, hence I can't see any reason why not to do the same for my desired problem. Maybe there is a direct link between those tasks or any other reduction of my problem to another well known problem for which complexity analysis has been done.

**Edit:**
An (for my case) equivalent problem is to determine the matrix $M$ such that $M$ satisfies 
$$ M_b \cdot M = M_a $$
where $M_a, M_b$ are representation matrices for $(a_1,...,a_n)$ and $(b_1,...b_n)$ for a fixed basis of the regarded $K(x)$ vector space. Therefore with polynomial matrix inversion I would achieve my goals, unfortunately this has time complexity $O^{\sim}(n^3 d)$ where $d$ denotes the maximal degree of the entries of the considered matrix (cf. [On the Complexity of Polynomial Matrix Computations](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/claude-pierre.jeannerod/papers/issac03.pdf)). But the complexity I'm looking for should be $O^{\sim}(n^\omega d)$.

I would appreciate any kind of help, recommendations or hint for the **name** of this problem.
Thank you very much!

Comment: It seems then that you're just looking to compute the matrix product $M=M_b^{-1}M_a$, right?

Comment: Also, are you saying that the matrices have entries in $K(x)$, or that the vector space under consideration is $K(x)$?

Comment: Yes, it would be sufficient to be able to compute $M = M_b^{-1}M_a$, but given the matrices $M_a, M_b$, say of degree $d$, computing the inverse $M_b^{-1}$ would be too expensive, see the link in my question.

The matrices are defined over $K(x)$, we consider the vector space $V$ of dimension $n$ over $K(x)$.

Comment: At the very least, we can say that computing $A^{-1}B$ is at most as bad as computing $A^{-1}b$ for $n$ columns $b$.

Comment: There exist many good libraries for doing this kind calculation. Some important questions are: (1) how big is $n$ in the applications you are considering, (2) does $M_b$ have any special structure you can exploit, (3) is there some performance requirement you need to hit?

Comment: @K. Miller:  I'm looking for an asymptotic running time of $O^{\sim}(n^\omega d)$ where $d$ denotes the maximum of the degrees of the entries of the considered matrix. I'm not doing any implementation, instead I want to reason the asymptotic running time of another algorithm which uses this computation.
There is no special structure to exploit. Do you know any references I may consider? We only have the parameters $n$ and $d$ from which the running time should depend on.

Comment: Unfortunately, for a general dense, square matrix you will be hard pressed to do better then $O(n^3)$ in practice. Even extremely fast linear algebra libraries such as the Intel MKL share this common feature. Even if you had $M_b$ stored as an orthogonal matrix and only had to perform matrix-matrix multiplication to compute $M$, your running time would still be $O(n^3)$, or maybe a bit better with a Strassen-like algorithm.

Comment: @ K. Miller: Reducing the running time to the one of matrix multiplication would deliver exactly the desired result: $O^{\sim}(n^\omega d)$.

Comment: But could there be another approach computing $M$ via solving an equation system? This would sound like possibly reducing the running time to matrix multiplication which would be sufficient.